# Import Bio module from Bash

Tags: bash, slurm, biopython

I'm working on a remote server with Linux.
I created a new environment and got biopython installed with conda:

```
conda create --name new_bio python=3.5
conda activate new_bio
conda install -c conda-forge biopython
```

import Bio works when I am running it inside python:

```
(new_bio) -bash-4.2$ python
Python 3.5.5 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul 23 2018, 23:45:43)
[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Bio
>>> exit()
```

import Bio works when I am running my script like this:

```
(new_bio) -bash-4.2$ python my_Bio_script.py
hello
```

my_Bio_script.py:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
print('hello')
```

But when I try to run my script with Bash :

```
(new_bio) -bash-4.2$ sbash my_bash.sh
```

my_bash.sh bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash
module load anaconda           ### load anaconda module
source activate new_bio        ### activating environment, environment 
must be configured before running the job


python my_Bio_script.py
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "T.py", line 1, in <module>
from Bio import SeqIO
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Bio'
```

I have to send it as a Slurm Job in a bash file.. what can I do?

Comment: I have tried python=3 /python=3.8 ...same results

Comment: Could you do `echo $PYTHONPATH` and `echo $PATH` in your interactive environment and in bash script?

Answer (score 0):

One potential way to start debugging is to print environment variables `PYTHONPATH` and `PATH`.

What I would recommend is, print `$PATH` and `$PYTHONPATH`. Analyse the python version and path, replicate the same inside the bash script.

Also, analyse the `~/.profile` as well as `~/.bashrc` file and see whether there is any discrepancy with `PATH`s for python.

Comment: echo $PYTHONPATH give me nothin:                                            
(new_bio) -bash-4.2$ echo $PYTHONPATH   AND                                          echo $PATH give me this:                                                                                               (new_bio) -bash-4.2$ echo $PATH
/home/nevosmic/.conda/envs/new_bio/bin:/storage/modules/bin:/storage/modules/packages/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin

Comment: what is the result of echo $PATH inside your bash script?

Comment: /storage/modules/packages/anaconda3/bin:/home/nevosmic/.conda/envs/new_bio/bin:/storage/modules/bin:/storage/modules/packages/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin

Comment: Both are different right? There is an additional /storage/modules/packages/anaconda3/bin. What is inside this?

Comment: There is alot...  python,  python3, anaconda, pyvenv... BUT no biopython.